# Snap shapes to grid when using the perspective tool

Tags: adobe-illustrator, perspective

This question is related to adobe illustrator.

As you know, the software allows the user to add a grid that helps to draw in perspective (the Perspective Grid Tool).

I drew a rectangle with its anchors exactly on the corners of the grid.

Now I decided that I want to change the location of the vanishing point or change the horizon height etc. so that the grid is not the same as before.

But I want the rectangle I drew first to be transformed according to the changes I made to the grid.

How can I do that?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to move the grid and have the objects move with it. You will likely need to reapply the object to the grid.  Sometimes it's better to draw your object flat (in 2D), make a copy of it, and then apply the copy to the grid.  That way, if you change the perspective grid, you can delete the graphic and apply another copy of the original flat 2D artwork to the grid.

Comment: Well it is really nice to have a perspective grid. But this feature I am looking for seems to me to be quite obvious for the software to provide the users. Can you set some anchors on the canvas? Maybe that way I can achieve what I want in an "indirect" way.

Comment: Illustrator has extremely limited 3D capabilities, ultimately it's a 2D tool.  It might be better to use a 3D modelling application such as Blender if you want to change the perspective or view of an object.  The only workaround for Illustrator that I know of is the one in my comment above. Sorry.

Comment: What I am looking for is a way to print to pdf an illustration of a 3d object, but in vector form. After my [previous question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/159087/), I decided to work with Adobe Illustrator to create an illusion of 3d as a 2d artwork, and then came across the perspective tool. Do you have another suggestion for me to achieve what I want?

Comment: Maybe possible using some CAD software, but I can't make any recommendations as that's not really my bag, sorry.

Comment: CAD software is the best for creating 3d objects. But the question is how to export the object as a vector graphics in perspective.

Comment: I googled it. Apparently AutoCAD can export a 3D view of a drawing to a PDF containing vectors.  There's a tutorial on [youtube here](https://youtu.be/tK5Bdf3X_Uc)

Comment: The 3D grid tool of adobe illustrator is entirely botched. It solves the exact wrong part of the problem of drawing perspective. It solves the problem of perspective drawing for a real novice and neglects possibility of having multiple grids (say you want to draw a rooftop slope), it rejects the idea of having a horizon line that is not horisontal (no dynamic drawings like a car running on a oval for example).... All of which is easy to do. I recommend a 3d capable CAD, autocad works, but so does any number of cad applications. Youll find that something like Rhino in this case is a good value.

Comment: But yes cad software dont deal with shading mostly line construction only. Theres several reasons for this but mainly because there is no mechanism for perspective divide in the vector standards that we use. Theres no good solution to what you want unfortunately. Yes its a entirely trivial problem form programming perspective... If you have 3D vector graphics programmers working for you (which are really rare)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Design your 3d object in a cad software (autocad, solidworks, blender etc.)
2. Export it to a dwg file
3. Add some colors in an artwork software
4. Convert to pdf and include it as a figure in your document